# Does AFNetworking have reconnect method after connection failed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

Is there any way can do reconnection after a connection has failed with AFNetworking?

If there is, can I control reconnection timeout and reconnection times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While, that's not a current feature of AFNetworking, the Foundation URL loading system that AFNetworking uses is quite robust, and will automatically do it's best to make requests work.

The best thing for you to do would be to re-request and do any messaging to the user in the failure block of your request operation.